# Is there a constant approximation algorithm for longest path for 3-connected cubic planar graphs or maximal planar graph?

Tags: graph-algorithms, approximation-hardness

**optimization problem**

**Input**: a 3-connected cubic planar graph

**feasible solution**: A simple path

**measure to optimize**: length of the simple path

Is there a constant approximation algorithm for this problem?

The Hamiltonian circuit problem on 3-connected cubic planar graphs is NP-Complete [in this paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr04/cos423/handouts/the%20planar%20hamiltonian.pdf).

A [relevant question about for cubic Hamiltonian graph](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/674/best-bounds-for-the-longest-path-optimization-problem-in-cubic-hamiltonian-graph) shows that there is no constant approximation algorithm for longest path on cubic graphs.

I'm also interested in the version where the input is a maximal planar graph.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the motivation for this particular problem for this particular class of graphs?  As a wild guess, is there any connection to the [Hirsch conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirsch_conjecture)?

Comment: I did not have Hirsch conjecture in mind. Consider the following problem: There is a planar embedding of a graph. One want to find a simple curve on the plane that maximizes the number of vertices visited without cross any edge twice. If there is a constant approximation for this problem, then there will be a constant approximation for the problem in the question.

Comment: Hmm, I have trouble understanding the motivation for your other problem (“find a simple curve on the plane that maximizes the number of vertices visited without cross any edge twice”), but thanks for the reply!